# How to convert differential equations to Maxwell's equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to convert the differential equation of a RL series circuit to Maxwells equations and i have been unable to find a way to do this. So, I greatly appreciate if someone can show or tell me how to do.

Comment: What do you mean convert one equation into another?  The Maxwell equations can be used to derive the RL equations.  Possibly more suited for the physics page?

Comment: All geometric information is lost in the equation of an RL circuit.  There would be no conceivable way to determine field equations involving Div, Grad and Curl from a lumped circuit ODE.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this equation: $$\frac{di}{dt}+\frac{R}{L}i=u_G$$
then maybe putting $$i=\frac{dq}{dt}\\
=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\epsilon_0 \,\mathrm{div}\vec{E}\right)=\epsilon_0 \,\mathrm{div}\left(\frac{d\vec{E}}{dt}\right)
\\
=\epsilon_0 \,\mathrm{div}\left(\frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial x^k}.\frac{dx^k}{dt}\right)\\
=\epsilon_0 \,\mathrm{div}\left(\frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial x^k}.\frac{dx^k}{dt}-\vec{J}\right)$$ will help you, but I didn't understand why do you want to derive the 4 equations of Maxwell from a simple RL circuit?

Answer (score 0):

By your question, I think that you intend to derive Maxwell's Equations from the differential equation describing an RL circuit assuming that you have no prior knowledge of Maxwell's Equations or of the physical construction of an inductor.  I contend that you cannot do so because the differential equation only has a time derivative and Maxwell's equations contain spatial derivatives (div and curl).  There is no way to infer from the RL equation that there are even fields at work.  You could say that the inductor is a coil and therefore infers that the physical flow of current in a coil has some significance, however, again the differential equation does not show that the inductor is in the form of a coil, it merely gives you a mathematical relationship between voltage and current, namely $V = \frac{d}{dt}I$.